# Load JS, Media and CSS on subdomain

Tags: javascript, css, media, domain

I currently load all my files on one domain.

I thought it would be better to load all js, media and css content from a subdomain, like:

http://media.domain.com
http://js.domain.com
http://css.domain.com

Does anybody know if this improve the speed positive?

Comment: yes ,sure it improve the site speed...But you need upload file js and css,media  files to your base site magent dir

Comment: dont forget that you need to properly configure cache and ignore cookies...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a subdomain on your server configuration and linking the root folder of the new subdomain to the js/css folders you want to server from there with something like

`ln -s /var/www/html/domain.com/magento/media /var/www/html/domain.com/cdn/media` for skin and js folders.

This [guide](http://twincreations.co.uk/serving-magento-media-images-from-a-sub-domain/) shows you how to achieve this on nginx, it should be pretty straightforward with apache too.

You can add some [expire headers](http://gtmetrix.com/add-expires-headers.html) for the resources in the vhost creation or in a .htacess too.

Then go to System > Configuration > Web > Unsecure and change {{unsecure_base_url}} to the new subdomain you created for all the resources you want to server from your local CDN. Same for Secure urls.

Comment: why does he have to do all this ?? creating a fake CDN is just pointing your subdomain to the same ip address as your main domain... nothing else, and change magento media url to `http://media.domain.com/media`. for any advanced CDN he needs to run any separate vps...

Comment: and your guide has no caching rules

Comment: @ADM create another answer or edit mine's if you think you can improve it.

Answer (score 1):

@ADM - because browsers will limit the amount of requests coming from a single domain.  With more domains, the browser will accept more connections hense making for a speedier overall render time